# How do you Round a Sum SQL

Tags: javascript, sum, rounding

I'm grabbing a sum from a database and using the sum to populate a js script that shows a donation thermometer of the progress.

```
Current Dontations: <?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT SUM(purchase_value) AS sum_total FROM wp_cmxi_edd_customers');
$var ='$total';
$total   = 0;
foreach ($results as $result):
   $total = $result->sum_total;
    break;
endforeach; 
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $total;?></td>
</tr>
```

The js:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var currentAmount = '<?php echo $var ;?>';
 </script>
```

The problem is, it's returning NaN becuase I need to round the number to remove the decimals.  How do you ROUND and SUM at the same time?

Comment: `ROUND( SUM(purchase_value) )` ?

Comment: I would round after summing for improved accuracy

Comment: or x = Math.round(20.49) // Returns the value 20 in JS